# Add milliseconds to log file timestamp

Tags: awk, sed, timestamp

I'm reviewing a log files from two different servers. I know the difference in time between these two servers down to the millisecond. To better understand the sequence of these messages I'm interested in adjusting one of the log files output to reflect the same time.

I usually use pass the log file through an awk script to do other things and then pipe the output to less. It looks like this:

```
~/path/to/myAwkscript.awk /path/to/my/logfile | less
```

My thought process is that I could use `sed`/`awk` to add 747 milliseconds to each timestamp in the file. I'm not opposed to other solutions. Each line (unless it is some kind of stack trace) begins with the `timestamp` in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,MS`

Here is example of the timestamp in my log:

```
2019-01-24 01:36:24,487
```

When I'm reviewing it I want that portion to read as follows:

```
2019-01-24 01:36:25,234
```

and then the rest of the line/file to be its original.

Thanks for reading.
-Gregg

Comment: Please show your own code first, how have you tried etc.  Also, show some sample input and your expected output.

Comment: @kvantour Thanks! You gave a A+ answer so far as I'm concerned regardless of whether it solved. Thank you! I briefly started stepping through the pieces you have. Thought to myself date function <E>. Truth - i haven't even had a chance to try. Curve ball after curve ball. And can appreciate Tiw response too. Didn't mean to offend. It was one of those very late nights where I'd been doing dumb things like separate from the comma because I just wasn't thinking. I thought someone might be up for a brain exercise. I will absolutely get to testing this and add the dopey things I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we do not know anything about your input file, we assume you can extract the date-time and manipulate it yourself in awk.

The trick is to use `mktime` with the date excluding the milliseconds. This will create an epoch time (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) where you can add the milliseconds. However, since the milliseconds are not representable as a floating point number, it is suggested to work in milliseconds instead of seconds. This way you can do everything with integers.

Example:

```
2019-01-24 01:36:24,487
=> mktime("2019 01 24 01 36 24")*1000 + 487
=> 1548293784487
```

This returns the total amount of milliseconds. You can now compare these numbers by adding the required 747 milliseconds to this number.

Why working in milliseconds? Most of the time, working in seconds, will not be problematic at all. You would get something like:

```
2019-01-24 01:36:24,487
=> mktime("2019 01 24 01 36 24") + 0.487
=> 1548293784.48699998855590820....
```

As you notice, this is not exactly the same number but rounded to the closest binary number. These slight rounding errors could potentially create minor inconsistencies which log entry came first.

The following example will sort the two files accordingly:

Here we assume `log1` needs the extra 747 miliseconds:

```
awk '{ time=$1" "$2; ms = substr(time,21,3); time=substr(time,1,19)
       gsub(/[-:]/," ",time); time=mktime(time)*1000 + ms }
     (NR==FNR) { time+=747 }
     { print time, FILENAME, $0 }' log1 log2 | sort -n
```

This will output something like:

```
1548293784487 log2 2019-01-24 01:36:24,487 entry
1548293784587 log2 2019-01-24 01:36:24,587 entry
1548293785234 log1 2019-01-24 01:36:24,487 entry
1548293785235 log2 2019-01-24 01:36:25,235 entry
...
```

**remark:** this makes use of the gnu-awk extension `mktime`.
**remark:** `mktime` will convert to epoch assuming that the presented string is in the local timezone of the server. If both logs are generated on servers with different time-zones, you would have to make a change to the code to reflect these time-zones. It is strongly recommended to always have your logs in UTC.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to get back to this. your solution works. it doesn't do exactly what I was looking for. but with reason which you've explained. thanks for your time and help.